# FragmentTabHost — No tab known for tag null?

Tags: android, android-studio

При просмотре activity_main.xml в визуальном редакторе появляются ошибки. Как их исправить?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:330)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>   at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
>   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:232)
>   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>   at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>   at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>   at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>   at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>   at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**MainActivity.java**

```html
package by.none.none.tabtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**FragmentTab.java**

```html
package by.none.none.tabtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если не считая сообщений визуального редактора всё работает, то проблема в глючном визуальном редакторе. Как написано по приведённой выше ссылке пользоваться им надо как можно меньше. В идеале - не пользоваться вовсе. И обращать внимания на его сообщения об ошибках тоже не надо.

Comment: Проблема не только в нем, приложение сразу же после запусука закрывается.

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что фрагмент, используемый вами, должен сначала добавиться в активити. Возможно поможет, засим, перенос инициализации `mTabHost` в `onResume` активити. А вообще вы используете старые решения. Сейчас табы делают совсем не так. Используйте `TabLayout` из `support-design` либы от гугла.

Comment: Благодарю, буду использовать новые библиотеки от google.